# Calcular la cantidad de productos que esta vendiendo un usuario

Tags: sql, pdo

estoy tratando de contar cuantos productos esta vendiendo cada usuario, pero mi lógica me falla un poco, me gustaría saber si me pueden ayudar con esto.

**Mi tabla Producto en la BD**

```
CREATE TABLE product(
id_producto             int(255) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
user_id                 int(255) not null,
title                   varchar(200) not null,
description_product     text not null,
moneda                  varchar(100) not null,
price                   varchar(200) not null,
ubication               varchar(150) not null,
video                   varchar(255),
miniatura               varchar(255),
images                  varchar(255) not null,
category                varchar(255) not null,
condicion               varchar(50) not null,
state                   varchar(100),
create_at_product       date,
CONSTRAINT fk_product_users FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id_usuario)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

Si necesitan mas información me la hacer saber por favor

**Un saludo**

Comment: Ocupamos tu consulta por favor, lo que hayas tratado al momento

Comment: @Aprendiz no entendí nada

Comment: Que para poder ayudarte debemos ver que consulta sql has tratado, una muestra del resultado esperado, que fallos has obtenidp

Comment: @Aprendiz he hecho esto, pero no ha funcionado, solo me dice que el usuario ha publicado 1 producto cuando en realidad ha publicado mas de 1 `// Sacar la cantidad de producto que ha publicado cada usuario
$stmt = $conexion->query("SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS cantidad FROM product GROUP BY user_id");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // cantidad de producto
    $cantidad = $row['cantidad'];

}`

Comment: Coloca una muestra de datos, pues la consulta parece correcta

Comment: @Aprendiz Como es una consulta de datos ?

Comment: Pues es la consulta que acabas de poner es una consulta sql para obtener datos .....

Comment: @Aprendiz ya lo he solucionando, el problema estaba en que no estaba colocando el **WHERE** `$profile = (int)$profile;

// Sacar la cantidad de producto que ha publicado cada usuario
$stmt = $conexion->query("SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS cantidad FROM product WHERE user_id = $profile GROUP BY user_id");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // cantidad de producto
    $cantidad = $row['cantidad'];

}` ya me muestra todo correctamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya he logrado resolver este problema y lo logre con esta consulta **sql**

```
$profile = (int)$profile;

// Calcular la cantidad de producto publicado por cada usuario
$stmt = $conexion->query("SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) AS cantidad FROM product WHERE user_id = $profile GROUP BY user_id");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // Almacenamos en esta variable la cantidad de productos
    $cantidad = $row['cantidad'];

}
```

**NOTA:** Soy nuevo en este foro y no se si esta bien o mal que haya respondido yo mismo a mi propia pregunta.